# Routing traffic to multiple non public IP systems

Tags: routing, cloud

We are a small startup and one of our basic requirements is to enable cloud access to our core system (running on a basic linux distribution) for our clients that often use a Internet connection with no public IP address.
The homekit runs a basic linux distribution 
Are there are open source packages that would enable a device sitting behind a private IP to connect to a cloud server while the cloud server routes the requests for each incoming request to a particular device depending on a token

---

Ok, let me rephrase the question
What I need to do it enable my clients to access a small webserver running on an embedded device at their home (in the simplest possible manner)
They will access this webserver (running on either port 80 or any custom port that I can configure)

The internet connection they will have at their home may or may not have a public IP. Moreover I can't ask them to fiddle around with port forwarding etc

Asking them to open a VPN connection before accessing this webserver would take away the entire user friendliness

A possible solution is that since the client base is expected to be small , I can configure each webserver to be on a unique port number (e.g. 3400-3500) and I use my own dedicated server as a broker (e.g. requests coming to say myserver.com at port 3400 is routed to client 1 , 3401 to client 2 and so on

Issues: Not very elegant, also would still need to figure out get their home servers to connect somehow to my dedicated server

Answer (score 1):

Any VPN solution will do. OpenVPN that connects from client to server (to cloud) will be nice solution, and you can easily tune the encryption level etc. And yes you can also filter who connects to your cloud if you wish to. Just don't forget to block inter-client traffic on server side!

As you are able to communicate with client you are free to use and kind of requests routing.

P.S. Don't know if the OpenVPN will fit you setup and h/w limits.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly - But wouldn't openVPN require me to setup a separate VPN for each client.
To draw an analogy, think of something like a Wemo Switch which connects to the cloud and a server at Belkin identifies and maps each incoming request to the corresponding Wemo and routes the request specifically to that one

Comment: Yes each client will setup different channel/link to server. But this allows you to pass over any network difficulties like firewalls and NAT. If you don't need that why can't you simple create http/https API on server so clients will initial 'conversation' from client side?

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution that wouldn't need customer action and would use the least moving parts needs a reverse connection and a connection broker.

You could reverse the connection ends, and get those "homekit" or "home servers" phone home (your servers) instead. This is called Reverse Tunneling, and can be used to bypass firewalls and dynamic IPs; and can be done with off-the-shelf open-source SSH, for low numbers of servers.

If you want to know how does SSH tunneling works, I recommend https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work .

Once those homeservers connect, transmit their internal network IPs (some custom glue code will be needed here, as well as some kind of way to make sure your untrusted clients don't step eachother), to the connection broker (your portal) and serve out their internal IPs (that hopefully only them can access).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to wrap my head around your issue but it sounds very similar to an IOT use case. Azure has an IOT Hub that allows you to have devices sending and receiving commands from remote locations. The connection is initiated on the client side so firewalls, and NAT don't break the connection. This might solve your problem, however you'd need to change the customer side device from a web server to an application listening to the hub, and then provide the interface on the cloud side.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/

I'm an MS employee, that's why the Azure specific answer. It's what I know.